# CKEditor multiple iframe dialog fields show the same dialog

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have created two CKEditor plugins. Each of them uses an "Iframe Dialog Field", meaning that a dialog box is launched and the contents of that dialog box is a webpage (you can think of the entire dialog box as being like one big iframe).

Each plugin works perfectly on its own. However if I use both plugins in the same CKEditor app, they both end up displaying the same page, rather than two different pages, despite the fact that they point to two different pages. I see no reason why this should be happening. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

---

To make sure there is no confusion, an "IFrame Dialog Field" is a dialog box whose contents are another webpage. 
Documenentation - http://ckeditor.com/addon/iframedialog

[ This is different from using an "IFrame dialog", which I believe is a plugin that lets the user add an iframe to the page.
Documentation - IFrame Dialog: http://ckeditor.com/addon/iframe ]

In terms of usage, when using an IFrame Dialog Field, you specify the url of the page to load in the addIframe() command. Here is an example of using a CKEditor Iframe dialog
https://gist.github.com/garryyao/1170303

---

Back to my issue - if I use just one of the plugins in my CKEditor, it works perfectly. Each plugin points at a different url, and opens that url as the contents of the dialog box. But, if I use both plugins in my CKEditor, although I see a different icon for each, both end up launching a dialog box which points to the same url. Depending which one I launch first, that is the url both end up opening. It is as if you are only allowed to use one IFrame Dialog Field in CKEditor, and the first one used overwrites all others.

This same question was asked a couple of years ago, with no response on the CKEditor forum. The person who asked the question posted his solution, or rather his workaround, which was to NOT use the IFrame Dialog Field altogether, but to instead use a regular dialog and then put an iframe element within it. 
http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/multiple-iframedialog-plugins-display-same-dialog

That seems like an OK workaround, but it is a workaround and not a solution. I haven't tried it yet, and don't know what potential issues I will run into if I go down that route. I'd prefer to fix my existing code rather than rewrite the plugins, unless I have no choice.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have not found any further information, or received any answers here, I ended up going with the workaround mentioned at the end of my question - I used a regular dialogue box and put a big Iframe within it. This problem doesn't exist with that approach, and It looks pretty much the same as an Iframe dialog box. (Considering the almost total lack of community support with CKEditor customization, I've realized it is better to just adjust your design/concept to do what is more easily accomplished with CKEditor, rather than get CKeditor to do exactly what you want).